# PHP code won't work with symbols, does work with words

Tags: php

How do I make a PHP string work with symbols? I have another set of strings using the same code below with words and it works. The current code doesn't show anything.

```
<?php $linktitle = get_the_title(); ?>
<?php $linkt = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, " –")); ?>
```

This is the original title:

> If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router – The New York Times

Comment: which is that character, looks like hipen, but actually not.

Comment: em dash – http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html

Comment: current output is `If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router ` right. please place output string that you want

Comment: Nothing. Blank space.

Comment: could you please put string that you want. right now I am not able understand  from where you want to cut string

Comment: remove `– The New York Times`. If I do a regular dash `-`, this is the output: `If Your Wi`

Comment: removal of the string `– The New York Times` is happening with the above code.

Comment: Not on my end, still blank.

Comment: `If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router` No matter what I do, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

`<?php $linktitle = get_the_title();?>
<?php $linkt = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, '&#8211;')); ?>`

HTML characters is what got it working. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working.

```
$string = 'If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router – The New York Times';

$linkt = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, " –"));
echo $linkt;
```

> Output is = "If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router"

something wrong with `get_the_title()` function. please check otherwise try this `get_the_title( $post_id )`

Thanks

Comment: Still not working. Must be using a wrong character to look for.

Comment: are you checked `get_the_title()` is working properly? because sometime you need to pass `$post_id` for getting title or else please put more code here so I can help you. thanks

Comment: I know this works because if I use other symbols that are in the title - like a comma and dash - it works. I don't know what character it is but I know the HTML character is `&#8211;` if that helps.